# PyQGIS changing the scale

Tags: pyqgis, scale

I am building a script where I need to set my scale of my added vector layer.  I get no errors with my script as written but the scale does not change.  FYI - I run this script through the plugin ScriptRunner:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

class OSMproject:
    def __init__(self, iface):
    self.iface = iface
    
def load_masks(self):
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    mask = QgsVectorLayer('B:\\USAF\\Section_1\\Masks Quarters\\USAF_D3_maskA1.shp','USAF_D3_maskA1'        
    project.instance().addMapLayer(mask)      
    activeLayer = self.iface.activeLayer()
    renderer = activeLayer.renderer()
    symbol = renderer.symbol()
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
    symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(61,105,249,255))
    
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    canvas.zoomScale(5000)
    canvas.refresh()

def run_script(iface):
    """Script runs by loading and calling LoadArea methods."""
        ap = OSMproject(iface)
        ap.load_masks()
```

Comment: Why do you use Script Runner? You can easily do that using QGIS Python Editor.

Answer (score 2):

As Matt states, the code has indentation issues, and also missing parts (`self`, parenthesis, `'ogr'`).

Use this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

def run_script(iface):
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    mask = QgsVectorLayer('path/to/file.shp', 'USAF_D3_maskA1', 'ogr')
    project.instance().addMapLayer(mask)
    activeLayer = iface.activeLayer()
    renderer = activeLayer.renderer()
    symbol = renderer.symbol()
    symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(61,105,249,255))

    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    canvas.zoomScale(5000)
    canvas.refresh()
```

Comment: Thx Kadir for the input.  I literally copied/pasted your script (changed the zoomScale to 5000), to try out and it still does not work?!?  I loaded a default, blank QGIS 3.28.  The scale shows 1:37317864. When I run the script in ScriptRunner the scale changes to 1:12581, which I assume it is changing to that to show the entire loaded shapefile.  But it is not changing to 1:5000?

Comment: And forgot to ask, you keep saying I have indentation issues.  Is that even with the script you posted?  If so, I do not understand where that issue is?  The other issues I see you corrected.

Comment: I take it the indentation issue you were referring to the line def run_script(iface):?  If so, I lined that up with the other defs.

Comment: I thought you run this Python Editor. I've added the script runner form. I removed the class. No need it. It works in Script Runner. Change file path.

Comment: The indentation issue is that you define your `load_mask` function outside your class (it is on the same indent level as the class itself). `ap.load_masks()` would throw an AttributeError. Perhaps it happened when you copied your code to your question?

Comment: Thank you for being patient here with me. Kadir, I ran you code change above and believe it or not it does not work... or I should say properly.  It did change finally to 5000 scale but now the mask does not show.  It loads the layer with an exclamation point.  Clicking on it says repair data source so I take it no longer can find the file as written.  I also now get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'symbol', which I take is related to the layer now displaying?  Matt, yes that was my mistake when I posted the script making the indentation incorrect.  Oooops.

Comment: As I build upon this script I think I will need the full path of the shapefile as it will eventually be automated to switch out filenames.  I thought using class is a good way to organize my script as I build?  I know this one is so small to really use it but as you can tell I am learning.

Comment: Interesting. If you run the script for an empty layer list, it doesn't change scale, but it zooms to layer extent by default. If there is a layer and you run the script, it changes the scale.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuMoi.gif

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the indentation is off in your question, but the problem appears to be that you are not referencing your `iface` object correctly. There is also an optional argument to ignore any scale locks on the map canvas.

Try:

```py
canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.zoomScale(5000, ignoreScaleLock=True)
```

Comment: Thx, tried it but still not working.